# Not able to delete correct object from json array

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

This is the json structure that I'm having...

```
{
  "comment": "Test123",
  "scheduleId": "291701",
  "observations": [
    {
      "typeId": 1,
      "comment": "Test",
      "categoryId": 852,
      "smateeId": 217094,
      "subCategoryId": 5726,
      "hasImage": false
    },
    {
      "typeId": 2,
      "categoryId": 861,
      "comment": "Hshh",
      "subCategoryId": 5825,
      "smateeId": 217094,
      "hasImage": false
    },
    {
      "subCategoryId": 5908,
      "smateeId": 217094,
      "typeId": 3,
      "comment": "Hehh",
      "categoryId": 870,
      "hasImage": false
    }
  ],
  "schedule": {
    "smatorIds": [
      19369,
      19370
    ],
    "workstationId": "196890",
     "plant": {
      "id": "2980",
      "gaiaCode": "k987976",
      "name": "ASDHKJK/ASDA"
    },
    "departmentId": "188848"
  },
  "shiftId": null
}
```

Now what I want to achieve is to remove a specific element from the `observations` array. In the `observations` array, the keys `typeId`, `categoryId`, `smateeId`, `subCategoryId` are not unique. So to have a unique value to identify each object I added a random number to the dictionary like so...

```
ArrayData.shared.obsIndex = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 10000)

    positiveObservationDict["smateeId"] = ArrayData.shared.smatReceiverIDArray1[0]
    positiveObservationDict["categoryId"] = Int(self.Category_Id)

    positiveObservationDict["typeId"] = 1
    positiveObservationDict["subCategoryId"] = Int(self.Sub_Category_Id)
    positiveObservationDict["comment"] = self.PO_Comments.text!

    positiveObservationDict["hasImage"] = false
    positiveObservationDict["tempID"] = ArrayData.shared.obsIndex

ArrayData.shared.arrayOfObservations.append(positiveObservationDict)
```

Now I have another dictionary twice into the same array like so...(I'm again adding a random number also into this dictionary)

```
ArrayData.shared.obsIndex = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 10000)

    newDict["smateeId"] = ArrayData.shared.smatReceiverIDArray1[0]
    newDict["categoryId"] = Int(self.Category_Id)

    newDict["typeId"] = 1
    newDict["subCategoryId"] = Int(self.Sub_Category_Id)
    newDict["comment"] = self.PO_Comments.text!

    newDict["hasImage"] = false
    newDict["tempID"] = ArrayData.shared.obsIndex

ArrayData.shared.arrayOfObservations.append(newDict)
```

So my new json structure after adding the random number looks like this...

```
{
  "comment": "Test123",
  "scheduleId": "291701",
  "observations": [
    {
      "typeId": 1,
      "comment": "Test",
      "categoryId": 852,
      "smateeId": 217094,
      "subCategoryId": 5726,
      "hasImage": false
      “tempID”: 2563    
    },
    {
      "typeId": 2,
      "categoryId": 861,
      "comment": "Hshh",
      "subCategoryId": 5825,
      "smateeId": 217094,
      "hasImage": false
      “tempID”: 765
    },
    {
      "subCategoryId": 5908,
      "smateeId": 217094,
      "typeId": 3,
      "comment": "Hehh",
      "categoryId": 870,
      "hasImage": false
      “tempID”: 174
    }
  ],
  "schedule": {
    "smatorIds": [
      19369,
      19370
    ],
    "workstationId": "196890",
     "plant": {
      "id": "2980",
      "gaiaCode": "k987976",
      "name": "ASDHKJK/ASDA"
    },
    "departmentId": "188848"
  },
  "shiftId": null
}
```

Now I want to delete the object with `tempID` 765. This is what I'm doing for that...

```
 let index = ArrayData.shared.arrayOfObservations.index(where: { dictionary in
      guard let value = dictionary["tempID"] as? Int
        else { return false }
      return value == ArrayData.shared.obsIndex
    })
    if let index = index {
        ArrayData.shared.arrayOfObservations.remove(at: index)
    }
```

But by doing this, the object that is deleted is the one with `tempID` 2563 instead of the one with `tempID` 765. How can I delete the correct object..?

EDIT: Also, in this place above `return value == ArrayData.shared.obsIndex` I cannot do something like this also `return value == 765`. I want to pass the exact value...

Comment: Try changing `return value == ArrayData.shared.obsIndex` to `return value == 765`

Comment: You probably don't want to use random for indexes as there is a chance that you end up with duplicate ids, which would could lead to difficult to track down issues. Can you use an auto incrementing integer instead?

Comment: I cannot hardcode as `return value == 765` @JoakimDanielson as I might get different ids at different times. I want to pass the id I want to delete..

Comment: Replacing 765 with a variable should be trivial

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is much simpler

```
let objectID = 765
if let index = ArrayData.shared.arrayOfObservations.firstIndex(where: { $0["tempID"] as? Int == objectID}) {
    ArrayData.shared.arrayOfObservations.remove(at: index)
}
```

or write a function

```
func deleteObject(withID objectID : Int) {
    if let index = ArrayData.shared.arrayOfObservations.firstIndex(where: { $0["tempID"] as? Int == objectID}) {
        ArrayData.shared.arrayOfObservations.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

and call it

```
deleteObject(withID: 765)
```

Comment: I cannot hard-code the value as `765` @vadian since I might get different ids at different times...

Comment: Then create a variable int to be deleted and pass to the function where you want to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need have proper information that which data you want to delete. Its not necessary that you should have unique id to delete the data.

Consider below data

```
"observations": [
        {
          "typeId": 1,
          "comment": "Test",
          "categoryId": 852,
          "smateeId": 217094,
          "subCategoryId": 5726,
          "hasImage": false
        },
        {
          "typeId": 2,
          "categoryId": 861,
          "comment": "Hshh",
          "subCategoryId": 5825,
          "smateeId": 217094,
          "hasImage": false
        }]

let observations = [Observation]()
let data = observations.filter({$0.typeId != 1})
```

This data will have only "typeId = 2" data. If you have multiple data with "typeId = 1", all the data which has "typeId = 1" will be removed and other typeId values will be leftover.